# Parameters with PDO for stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

How to call a SQL Server's stored procedure with 2 parameters in PDO.

For example in SQLServer's prompt:

EXEC Test 'arg1', 'arg2'

What is the next step in PHP with PDO?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

To use muliple parameters, just use bindParam for each parameter, either with named parameters:

```
$query="EXEC test :arg1, :arg2";
$stmt->bindParam(":arg1",$first_variable);
$stmt->bindParam(":arg2", $second_variable);

$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

Another way is to directly hand the parameters to the execute()-method as an array:

```
$stmt->execute(array(":arg1"=>$first_variable,":arg2"=>$second_variable
```

You can also use question marks for all parameters in the query:

```
$query="EXEC test ?,?";
...
...
$stmt->bindParam(1, $first_variable);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $second_variable);
```

or directly inside the execute():

```
$stmt->execute(array($first_variable, $second_variable));
```

Comment: I have already tried in the stored procedure, and it works in the SQL Server. 

In SQLServer I have one result, but in PHP I have no result.

Do you know why?

Comment: I tried it, and it worked fine.
Just to be sure: how did you call the procedure in php? Could you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

I typically use question marks for parameters in PDO, I.E.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET name=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($name, $id));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

You can read a great explanation of PDO query structures [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)